# How to make ticks not extend past left of chart?

Tags: angular, chart.js

Am using Chart.js to make a multi line chart. My issue is that the first tick extends past the left of the chart which shifts the entire thing over to make room. I'd like to make it so the first tick does not impact the positioning of the chart (which I'm aware does make the tick spacing slightly uneven for the first tick).

There are about 15 million options in Chart.js and I can't seem to make any of them work.

Here is a picture of what I'm seeing. That black line is added by me after the fact and demonstrates how the line starts there but the `Feb 6` tick sticks out to the left while the `Mar 6` tick does not.

[image: Picture of chart]

Here's my scale options at the moment:

```js
x: {
  type: 'time',
  ticks: {
    display: true,
    stepSize: 7,
  },
  grid: {
    drawTicks: false,
    display: false,
  },
  border: {
    display: true,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try to change the ticks alignment, something like the following:

```
x: {
  type: 'time',
  ticks: {
    display: true,
    stepSize: 7,
    align: 'inner' // to align the start and end ticks in the chart area width
  },
  grid: {
    drawTicks: false,
    display: false,
  },
  border: {
    display: true,
  },
},
```